# passing multiple instances of the same class through objects

Tags: python

```
class Card:
allRanks=(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
allSuits=('Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs')

def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    self.rank=rank
    self.suit=suit.capitalize()

def getRank(self):
    if self.rank in Card.allRanks:
        return self.rank
    else:
        print 'Please enter a number from 2 to 14\n14 => ACE\n11 => JACK\n12 => QUEEN\n13 => KING\n'
        exit()

def getSuit(self):
    if self.suit in Card.allSuits:
        return self.suit
    else:
        print 'There are only 4 suits in a pack!'
        exit()

def __str__(self):
    translate={11:'Jack',12:'Queen',13:'King',14:'Ace'}
    r = self.rank
    if r in range(11,15):
        myrank=translate[r]
    elif r in range(2,11):
        myrank=str(r)
    else:
        print "Sorry wrong card"
        exit()
    return myrank+' of '+self.suit

def __lt__(self,other):
    return (self.rank > other.getRank())

#c=Card(1,'spades')

class Deck:

def __init__(self):
    self.deck=[Card(i,j) for i in Card.allRanks for j in Card.allSuits]
    #for i in Card.allRanks:
    #    for j in Card.allSuits:
    #        self.deck.append(Card(i,j))

def shuffle(self):
    from random import shuffle


class Dealer(object):

    def __init__(self, deck, cards, num_players):
        self.deck=deck
        self.num_players=num_players
        self.cards=cards

    def deal(self):
        self.deck.shuffle()
        deal_list=[[] for i in range(self.num_players)] #returns a list of lists
        #say you have 4 players you will have [[hand1],[hand2],[hand3],[hand4]] where hand1=[5 cards]
        #now you pass this to the hand variable
        for i in range(self.cards):
            for j in range(self.num_players):
               deal_list[j].append(self.deck.topCard())
        return deal_list

class Dealer_better(object):

    def __init__(self, deck, cards, *args):
        self.deck=deck
        self.cards=cards

    def deal(self):
        self.deck.shuffle()
        deal_list=[[] for i in range(len(*args))] #returns a list of lists
        #say you have 4 players you will have [[hand1],[hand2],[hand3],[hand4]] where hand1=[5 cards]
        #now you pass this to the hand variable
        for i in range(self.cards):
            for j in (*args):
                j.append(self.deck.topCard())


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, hand=[]):
        self.hand=hand
```

Hi I have classes Dealer and Dealer_better. It accepts objects from Deck() and has to deal cards to n number of players.

In class Dealer I pass the number of players that I need to deal the cards to directly as a variable and generate a list of lists where the hand of each player is a list.

I would like to make this better in Deal_better and pass the player objects directly to Deal_better after initializing multiple instances of **Class Player**. Is there a way to pass *player_objects similar to *args.

So that I can get the following functionality,

    `p1=Player()
    p2=Player()
    p3=Player()
    p4=Player()
    new_d=Dealer_better(Deck(),p1.hand,p2.hand,p3.hand,p4.hand)
    new_d.deal()`

print p1.hand should give me player one's hand, or atleast the objects in it.
I could write an add_card method in player to append to self.hand if need be.

pasting the classes in question below for clarity.

```
 class Dealer(object):

    def __init__(self, deck, cards, num_players):
        self.deck=deck
        self.num_players=num_players
        self.cards=cards

    def deal(self):
        self.deck.shuffle()
        deal_list=[[] for i in range(self.num_players)] #returns a list of lists
        #say you have 4 players you will have [[hand1],[hand2],[hand3],[hand4]] where hand1=[5 cards]
        #now you pass this to the hand variable
        for i in range(self.cards):
            for j in range(self.num_players):
               deal_list[j].append(self.deck.topCard())
        return deal_list
```

**versus**

```
class Dealer_better(object):

def __init__(self, deck,cards, *players):
    self.deck=deck
    self.cards=cards
    self.players = players

def deal(self):
    self.deck.shuffle()
    for i in range(self.cards):
        for p in range(len(self.players)):
            self.players[p].addCard(self.deck.topCard())
            print self.players[p].name,len(self.players[p].hand)


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, name, hand=[]):
        self.hand=hand
        self.name=name

    def addCard(self,card):
        self.hand.append(card)
```

Returns

`p1=Player('Bob')
    p2=Player('Lola')
    p3=Player('Luigi')
    p4=Player('Mario')
    new_d=Dealer_better(Deck(),5,p1,p2,p3,p4)
    new_d.deal()
    print len(p1.hand)`

Returns 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something along the lines of:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = []

class dealer(object):
    def __init__(self, *decks): #feel free to add more stuff this is just an example :)
        self.decks = [d for d in decks]

    def deal(self):
        for d in self.decks:
            d.append(1) # just an example
            d.append(2)


p1 = player()
p2 = player()
p3 = player()

d = dealer(p1.d,p2.d,p3.d)
d.deal()
print p1.d # was changed by deal
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/D6uARz))

Comment: I like the idea of the approach. Well Deal() needs to be provided to Dealer. For intance Dealer(Deck(),p1,p2 and so on)

Comment: Well I was just trying to demonstrate what you were looking for, you are free to change it as you wish :)

Comment: @user2755526 and please don't use default empty list see [this](http://ideone.com/dPmqkS)

Comment: @Scis Why not use new-style classes?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Where have I mentioned anything against it ?

Comment: @Scis I mean in your code. It's Python2 or you couldn't get away with `print ` so `class ClassName:` is old-style.